# SQL Server Admin Tools Automatically Uninstalled

Tags: sql-server

My computer did a windows update overnight and now I can't log on to the database through SSMS.  I have gotten this error before and all I would do is fire up SQL Server Admin Tools, start the database engine and I'm good to go. However, it seems Admin Tools have somehow been uninstalled by this update. I have SQL Server 2014 installed locally on my machine. How can I re-download the Administrative Tools?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean SQl Server configuration manager? Are you using Windows 10? Have you read the note in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Probably the worst "feature" of Windows 10 is needing to search for the program exe before it will show up in the Start menu.

Comment: Yes Windows 10. It's not SQL Server configuration Manager though. Perhaps it's not called SQL Server Admin Tools.  It basically lets you start/stop the database engine, sql server agent, SSRS, SSIS etc... and you can specify if you want them to fire up automatically or manually.

Comment: That's SQl Server configuration manager @MilesToGoBeforeISleep .

Comment: Oops.. oh yeah. haha.  I'm so frazzled right now, I can't think straight. Any ideas why it doesn't show up anymore?

Comment: OMG Windows somehow merged the SQL Server Configuration Manager within their Computer Management app. Why would it do that??

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the extension association. Both call the windows management console (.msc) plugin.

Comment: Yep, it uses MMC. If you want the icon back just create a shortcut. My SQLServerManager was located in SysWOW64 `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe /32 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc`